# Create New DF Col values where Time Range Between X and Y

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAo5l.png)I'd like to create a new column whose value is dependent on another column containing datetime or time data. So when time is between `[x]` and `[y]`, value of new column is `Z` where `Z` is an integer.

I know that `df['newColumn'] = np.where(df['price']>=100, 'yes', 'no')` creates a new column with yes and nos when the price is more than 100. I want to do something similar with my Panda data frame, specifying if time range between X and Y, add "1" to new column, elif time range between X2 and Y2, add "2" to column and so on.

I did see `df.loc['2002-1-1 01:00:00':'2002-1-1 04:00:00']` as a means of selecting a time range but couldn't quite put the two together. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Can you add data sample (5 rows) with expected output?

Comment: Sure Jezrael. I tried:
X['CLASS'] = np.where(X['Datetime']<='2010-03-12 16:49:00','1','0')
Which works but only does less than a value rather than a range. Trying to develop that idea further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with `np.where` or cast boolean to `int`s and then to `string`s:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2010-03-12 15:00:00', periods=10, freq='20H')
X = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': rng})  

mask = X['Datetime'].between('2010-03-12 16:49:00', '2010-03-14 16:49:00')
#solution1
X['CLASS'] = np.where(mask,'1','0')
#solution2
#X['CLASS'] = mask.astype(int).astype(str)

print (X)

             Datetime CLASS
0 2010-03-12 15:00:00     0
1 2010-03-13 11:00:00     1
2 2010-03-14 07:00:00     1
3 2010-03-15 03:00:00     0
4 2010-03-15 23:00:00     0
5 2010-03-16 19:00:00     0
6 2010-03-17 15:00:00     0
7 2010-03-18 11:00:00     0
8 2010-03-19 07:00:00     0
9 2010-03-20 03:00:00     0
```

EDIT:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2010-03-12 16:35:00', periods=30, freq='T')
X = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime': rng})  

#same output as below
#conditions = [X['Datetime'] < '2010-03-12 16:39:00', 
#              (X['Datetime'] < '2010-03-12 16:49:00') & (X['Datetime']>= '2010-03-12 16:39:00'),
#              X['Datetime']>='2010-03-12 17:01:00'] 

conditions = [X['Datetime'] < '2010-03-12 16:39:00', 
              X['Datetime'].between('2010-03-12 16:39:00','2010-03-12 16:48:00'),
              X['Datetime']>='2010-03-12 17:01:00'] 

classes = ['0','1','2'] 
#gaps are repalced to NaNs
X['CLASS'] = np.select(conditions, classes, default=np.nan)

#if want bin all data without gaps
bins = pd.DatetimeIndex(['1900-01-01', '2010-03-12 16:38:00', '2010-03-12 16:48:00', '2262-04-11'])
labels=['0','1','2'] 
X['label'] = pd.cut(X['Datetime'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=True)
```

---

```
print (X)

              Datetime CLASS label
0  2010-03-12 16:35:00     0     0
1  2010-03-12 16:36:00     0     0
2  2010-03-12 16:37:00     0     0
3  2010-03-12 16:38:00     0     0
4  2010-03-12 16:39:00     1     1
5  2010-03-12 16:40:00     1     1
6  2010-03-12 16:41:00     1     1
7  2010-03-12 16:42:00     1     1
8  2010-03-12 16:43:00     1     1
9  2010-03-12 16:44:00     1     1
10 2010-03-12 16:45:00     1     1
11 2010-03-12 16:46:00     1     1
12 2010-03-12 16:47:00     1     1
13 2010-03-12 16:48:00     1     1
14 2010-03-12 16:49:00   nan     2
15 2010-03-12 16:50:00   nan     2
16 2010-03-12 16:51:00   nan     2
17 2010-03-12 16:52:00   nan     2
18 2010-03-12 16:53:00   nan     2
19 2010-03-12 16:54:00   nan     2
20 2010-03-12 16:55:00   nan     2
21 2010-03-12 16:56:00   nan     2
22 2010-03-12 16:57:00   nan     2
23 2010-03-12 16:58:00   nan     2
24 2010-03-12 16:59:00   nan     2
25 2010-03-12 17:00:00   nan     2
26 2010-03-12 17:01:00     2     2
27 2010-03-12 17:02:00     2     2
28 2010-03-12 17:03:00     2     2
29 2010-03-12 17:04:00     2     2
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, yours looks more elegant than mine. Just solved it around same time with:
    conditions = [X['Datetime'] < '2010-03-12 16:39:00', (X['Datetime'] < '2010-03-12 16:49:00') & (X['Datetime']>= '2010-03-12 16:39:00'),X['Datetime']>='2010-03-12 17:01:00']
classes = ['0','1','2']
X['CLASS'] = np.select(conditions, classes, default=np.nan)

Comment: Jezrael - quick question, if you had three or more classes (as with the solution above) how would you modify it - maybe mask = [X['Datetime'].between('',''),(next criteria in brackets),(next criteria in brackets)]?

Comment: OK, I am working on it. But I have question - there is no class betwen `2010-03-12 16:49:00` and `2010-03-12 17:00:00` ?

Comment: Between #16:39:00# and #16:49:00# Class 1
Between #16:51:00# and #16:54:00# Class 2
Between #16:56:00# and #16:59:00# Class 3
Between #17:01:00# and #17:04:00# Class 4

I'm thinking I'll combine the conditions, classes approach above with your mask, and list the conditions as I did earlier.

Comment: OK, and between `16:49:00` and `16:51:00` is no class?

Comment: I edit answer, please check it. Some times are changed also.

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, much appreciated - lovely city Bratislava - I visited a few years ago. Best Regards NW